# HTML5 notifications

Tags: html, html5-notifications

Is anyone using HTML5 notifications in practice, and is there any value in doing so? From my understanding it's limited only to Chrome, and so I can't imagine people jumping on this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Google's now using them in [Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/desktop-notifications-for-emails-and.html). I think it'll prove popular and other sites will start running Chrome-only notifications. Then it will get implemented into WebKit so that Safari has it also. Then Firefox will do an implementation and I suspect *eventually* it'll get standardized.

If it's not hard to support (and it doesn't [look to be](http://0xfe.blogspot.com/2010/04/desktop-notifications-with-webkit.html)), then I'd do it. You'll delight the users that have Chrome without adversely affecting the experience for the rest of the users.

Answer (score 0):

Because Google is pushing to make this a [W3 html5 standard.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-notifications-20130912/)